# Getting the output of a single returned variable out of many in Python

Tags: python, function, return, iteration, parameter-passing

How can I only get either the first or the second return only by running a def function. I am trying to only get the value for the addition for `WhatIsA` and I am only trying to get the multiplication value for `WhatIsB`. I know that the code below is not convenient but I just want to know if there is a way to specify the only index of the return values as you run the program like `a[0]` or `b[1]`. How would I be able to do that?

```
def WhatIsA(value1, value2):
    a[0] = Values(value1,value2)
    return a[0]

def WhatIsB(value1, value2):
    b[1] = Values(value1,value2)
    return b[1]


def Values(value1,value2):
    a = value1+value2
    b = value1*value2
    return a, b

print(WhatIsA(10, 15))
print(WhatIsB(2, 12))
```

Output:

```
(25, 150)
(14, 24)
```

Expected Output:

```
25
24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function `Values()`is a must, then put this `a,b = Values(value1,value2)` in both the functions `WhatIsA` and `WhatIsB`.

```
def WhatIsA(value1, value2):
    a,b = Values(value1,value2)
    return a

def WhatIsB(value1, value2):
    a,b = Values(value1,value2)
    return b
```

Update:
you are assigning to a specific index and returning that value. Instead, assign it as whole and  use index to return it.

```
def WhatIsA(value1, value2):
    a = Values(value1,value2)
    return a[0]

def WhatIsB(value1, value2):
    b = Values(value1,value2)
    return b[1]
```

Comment: Ideal method to use

Comment: I have not been able to explain my question very well so i just updated the code please do let me know if that makes more sense

Comment: @georgehere okay, understood. I'll update it

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a tuple from the Values() function. This tuple is created upon assigning a value to Values(). What you want to do is index the tuple upon returning it as follows.

```
def WhatIsA(value1, value2):
    a = Values(value1,value2)
    return a[0]

def WhatIsB(value1, value2):
    b = Values(value1,value2)
    return b[1]


def Values(value1,value2):
    a = value1+value2
    b = value1*value2
    return a, b

print(WhatIsA(10, 15))
print(WhatIsB(2, 12))
```

Comment: I know that but I was curious if I can filter out a function with multiple returns. like instead of having `a,b = Values(value1,value2)` I would just have `a[0] = Values(value1,value2)`. I know that the code above is not convenient just want to filter the return value.

Comment: I have updated the code hopefully that is more clear